# SendGrid white label domain without causing conflicts

Tags: dns, sendgrid, cname

We're using SendGrid to handle emails on all of our websites but are experiencing some issues with spam filters etc. and want to effectively white label our domain, but it's a little complex:

We are hosting several versions of a website in our domain - the same website for different clients, so we'll have:

1. client1.ourdomain.com
2. client2.ourdomain.com
   etc.

We are using one SendGrid account to handle emails for all the websites, but when sending the email we change the from address to look like it's come from the client's own domain:

- noreply@client1.com for example, which may or may not exist.

So the emails are being sent by SendGrid on behalf of ourdomain.com but are labelled @client1.com.

Is it possible to create a default white label for the ourdomain.com that will affect white labeling for all SendGrid use where we've used a custom From address?

Another way to explain would be that we want every email sent from our domain, regardless of the address detail used, to be white labelled and remove things like 'via SendGrid.net'.

I hope that's enough detail.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this use case. You can't send on behalf of domains you don't control and have email auth checks pass. It's not possible. This is also a strategy that will cease to work on an increasing number of providers (including gmail) very soon due to strict DMARC policies becoming common. You need to rearchitect.

Comment: @bwest Even though we're not actually sending emails from those domains? they're just labelled as being from that domain rather than actually being sent from them.

Comment: Yes, that's one specific thing that DMARC is intended to stop. That's the same tactic that e.g. phishing emails use. This may help: https://sendgrid.com/blog/email-authentication-explained/

Comment: @bwest that makes a lot of sense. I think we were just looking for an easy method to begin with. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: No problem! It's an okay strategy if you can get your users to make DNS changes, but that's a fragile/time-consuming process

Comment: @bwest Any chance you could point me in the right direction for a better strategy? I'm fairly new to handling emails this way, perhaps I can suggest it to the business as a way to improve things.

Comment: Of course! Please send me an email to brandon@sendgrid.com and copy community@sendgrid on it. We're here to help.